# How to stop Gigabyte Designaire X399 / Threadripper 1920x from crashing on resume from sleep with TPM enabled?

Tags: uefi, power-management, tpm

When I try to put my Windows 10 (version 1809) PC to sleep, it will not resume correctly, and seems to wipe the TPM settings, meaning I have to recover using my Bitlocker recovery key.  Is there anything I can do to stop this happening?

My system configuration is as follows: AMD Threadripper 1920x, Gigabyte Designaire EX X399 motherboard, 4x8GB ECC PC4-2666 memory, MSI N760 Twin Frozr OC graphics.

Answer (score 2):

This was a really tricky problem to debug.  It appeared that the problem lay with my graphics card, which had a legacy Video BIOS that did not support UEFI.  I flashed the card with a UEFI version of the BIOS from the [MSI forums](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=264481.0), and I was then able to put the computer to sleep and resume without difficulty.  I still don't know why it interfered with the TPM module, but this does seem to have fixed the problem.